# No such file or directory: '/elrondsdk/vmtools/mandos-test'

Tags: python, multiversx, erdpy

I'm trying to run the tests for the contract from this tutorial, https://docs.elrond.com/developers/tutorials/your-first-dapp/, but I'm stumbling upon the below error when running `erdpy contract test`

```
INFO:projects.core:run_tests.project: /home/mccuna/repos/elrond/adder/adder
INFO:myprocess:run_process: ['/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/vmtools/mandos-test', '/home/mccuna/repos/elrond/adder/adder/mandos'], in folder: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/bin/erdpy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/erdpy/cli.py", line 32, in main
    _do_main()
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/erdpy/cli.py", line 58, in _do_main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/erdpy/cli_contracts.py", line 171, in run_tests
    projects.run_tests(args)
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/erdpy/projects/core.py", line 65, in run_tests
    project.run_tests(directory, wildcard)
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/erdpy/projects/project_base.py", line 106, in run_tests
    myprocess.run_process(args, env=tool_env)
  File "/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/erdpy-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/erdpy/myprocess.py", line 19, in run_process
    output = subprocess.check_output(args, shell=False, universal_newlines=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env, cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mccuna/elrondsdk/vmtools/mandos-test'
```

I've searched for a way to install `mandos-test`, but couldn't find anything useful. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: if running in a WSL environment, that might be the issue.

Ok, I've managed to side-fix the issue.

Initially, I was running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL2. After trying various solutions (e.g.: updates, reinstalling dependencies etc.) I've given up. I've removed the Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 environment and instead went for having an actual Ubuntu 20.04 installation, alongside Windows 10 and dual booting between them. Everything ran smoothly in the new, standalone, Ubuntu environment. My guess is that some dependencies are either not installed or not properly configured in a WSL2 environment, but considering my current erdpy & elrond tech stack experience, I cannot confirm or pinpoint the exact root cause.